# elasticsearch. How to count distinct value by date?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the same issue to count distinct value by date, that is the same issue mentioned here:
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Count-distinct-value-by-date-td4036320.html
This issue was posted a year ago. Is there any new update?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a concept of "distinct" in ElasticSearch, but by using nested [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#search-aggregations), you can accomplish the same thing:

1. Group by datetime
2. Subgroup by unique identifier
3. Count the results to get distinct counts

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "dt": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "datetime",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "unique_identifier"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```